# Make filter field for tag synonym case insensitive

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-synonyms

On the [tags synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) page filter field is case sensitive now:

> [image: eg]

Due to all tags are named in lower case, I suggest to make this field case insensitive, to prevent such situations like auto capitalization of the first word letter during input on my iPad:

> [image: no results]

Comment: Tag search also case sensitive :(

Comment: @Suvitruf which one? Search the tag via top bar is case insensitive as well as on [tag page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags).

Comment: I've tried it on https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags. And pretty sure it was case sensitive yesterday. Or, maybe,I was drunk ╮(︶▽︶)╭